# mouse will not appear on virtual box 6 with centos7

Tags: virtualbox, centos-7

I have virtual box 6.0.2 installed as well as centos7 with an 1804 dvd iso and am trying to set it up currently however I cannot see any mouse within centos. I also have ubuntu downloaded on my virtual box 6.0.2 and I can see and use the mouse within that just not centos.

Comment: What is the primary OS, how many VMs are set up, and what is in each one?

Comment: @fixer1234 I just uninstalled and installed an older version of virtual box. Apparently it's a known issue with v6